# Is it possible to open terminals in a grid layout when using ClusterSSH?

Tags: ssh, terminal, cluster

I'm using the [ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page) tool (using the `cssh` command) to admin clusters of between 4 and 8 machines.

By default, each terminal onto a cluster host is tiled, and opened to the right of the previous, so terminals to hosts 1-4 would be opened like:

```
1 2 3 4
```

When I connect to an 8 host cluster, this ends up with 8 terminals being tiled across two monitors, and I usually need to drag the windows back into a sensible layout.

What I'm looking for is a way to have these opened in a grid, so that the terminal layout looks more like:

```
1  2
3  4
```

Including something similar for an 8 host cluster.

If the application doesn't support it directly, are there any other simple scripts/methods/commands to layout a set of windows?  I'm mostly using Ubuntu (Gnome desktop) if that helps.